# Второй поток не хочет стартовать при запуске 2 серверов в потоках.

Tags: python, многопоточность

В общем, собираюсь запустить 2 сервера. Один будет слушать сообщения, другой будет делать то, что написано в сообщении.

Столкнулся с проблемой в потоках. Второй поток не хочет стартовать. 
Вот код:

```
from threading import Thread
def serverpic():
    x = 0
    while True:
        x= x+1
        if x == 1000: 
            print("test thread serverpic")
            x=0

def serverms():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i=i+1
        if i == 1000: 
            print("test thread serverms")
            i = 0

serverth = Thread(target=serverpic)
serverth.start()
serverth.join()

serverms = Thread(target=serverms)
serverms.start()
serverms.join()
```

Comment: У вас стоит serverth.join соответственно пока не закончит свою работу поток программа так и будет стоять на этой строчке и не дойдет до запуска следующего потока.

Comment: Перенесите `serverth.join` на строчку ниже `serverms.start`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало)

Answer (score 2):

У вас `serverth.join` вызывается до запуска второго процесса. Данный метод ждет завершения потока и только потом возвращает управление. Соответственно пока не закончит свою работу поток `serverth` программа так и будет стоять на этой строчке и не дойдет до запуска потока `serverms`.

Для правильной работы достаточно перенести serverth.join на строчку ниже serverms.start.